# Deferred jquery 201 Post created going in reject

Tags: jquery, deferred

```
postData: function (url, data) {
    var deferred = Q.defer();

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: url,
        data: JSON.stringify(data),
        dataType: "json",
        beforeSend: function (xhr, settings) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + window.access_token);
            xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");
        },
        success: function (data, responseText, jqXHR) {
            deferred.resolve(data, responseText, jqXHR);
        },
        error: function (e) {
            deferred.reject(e);
        }
    });

    return deferred.promise;
}
```

I don't understand why my request is going inside error callback

[image]

Comment: The server returns 201 i need to handle that ..

Comment: That's very odd. Any `2xx` response code should be considered as a `success`.

Comment: are you sure you are returning valid json? $.ajax will go to error if there is a parse error also

Comment: Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8 is the response Content-Type

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on comments that you are returning html you need to set appropriate `dataType`

`$.ajax` will also go to error if there is a parse error of the requested dataType. You can confirm this by logging the arguments of the error handler  `error: function (xhr, statusText, errorThrown)`

Try changing

```
dataType:'json'
```

To

```
dataType:'html'
```

Or remove that property as jQuery will know from the Content Type header